# Simple hard coded ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, hard-coding

Is it possible to do something like this in Android? (basically the equivalent of `select` and `option` in HTML):

```
<ListView android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <ListViewItem>TEST</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>TEST1</ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

I have tried this, it obviously doesn't work. All I can find online is information about using adapters, but as I have some hard coded values I don't need to use an adapter - I'm happy to put it directly in the XML file.

Is this possible?

Comment: No it is not possible in android.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1 ] Create a String array in strings.xml

2 ] Use the following attribute inside Listview tag 
    android:entries="@array/your_array_name"

Done !

Comment: Complete demonstration can be found here  http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-creating-and-populating-listview-items-in-xml/

Answer (score 1):

No It is not possible in android but used [android:entries](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android:entries) properties to load list item using String resource array.